# Try reinstalling `node-sass` on node 0.12?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I would like to use google web starter kit. I installed node.js v0.12.0, `node-sass` & `gulp`.

And then ran:

```
$ sudo npm install
```

When I typed `gulp serve` then got this error:

```
Using gulpfile ~/web-starter-kit/gulpfile.js Starting 'styles'... 'styles' errored after 93 ms 
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`? at getBinding
```

I reinstalled node and gulp but this doesn't help.

What should I do next?

Comment: Downgrading node worked for me.

Answer (score 385):

If your node version is 4 and you are using gulp-sass, then try

```
npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass

npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2
```

Comment: fixed problem form me on node 4.1 :) ty

Comment: Fixed for me on Debian 8.1 and Node 4.1 too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@3 did the job for me! :P

Comment: Thank you. Probably this answer should be marked as the "right one")

Comment: Thank you, spent a lot of time trying to resolve this and this was the solution that worked!

Comment: This is the only solution working on node 4.2.3. Thanks!

Comment: Using Win 8 and node 4+. This is the only solution that works, tried them all, literaly

Comment: Yep this worked for me. Tried the other fixes such as rebuilding sass and none of them worked. I guess they're all related to different version of sass and node!

Comment: Thank you so much! Mac, node v4.2.6

Comment: Thanks man! Just came across this issue and this fixed it for me :)

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution for Mac and node 5.8.

Comment: After running these commands, I had to run 'npm rebuild node-sass' then I was back in biz!

Comment: Note that you may have to run the sudo command in front of it for permission issues ;-)

Comment: Also solves the issue on v6.9.2 as of December 2016.  Thanks!

Answer (score 341):

I found this useful command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

From the `rebuild` [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild):

> This is useful when you install a new version of node (or switch node
>   versions), and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new node.js
>   binary.

http://laravel.io/forum/10-29-2014-laravel-elixir-sass-error

Comment: Got a lot of errors, like `Python not supported by` and `Failed at the node-sass@0.8.6 install script 'node build.js'`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it does minimum work to fix the actual problem.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: Make sure that you have Python installed and the _PYTHON_ environment variable set to point the installation.

Comment: I tried this before anything else and it worked perfectly. Cheers

Comment: I receive a ```Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp'```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 233):

I ran into this error using node `0.12.0` and it was fixed by deleting the existing `/node_modules` directory and running `npm update`.

Comment: That won't work if you don't have all you dependencies specified in package.json

Comment: I had to delete the folder, then run npm install, then npm update. But this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting the node_modules folder caused:
`Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'` when running `npm update`.

Comment: This is the drastic solution.  Just use `npm rebuild node-sass` which is specifically for rebuilding the C++ addons.

Comment: I believe we ran into this problem with an internal project because of a node_modules directory that was accidentally committed along with the source into source control.

Comment: Just running `npm update` worked for me. No need to delete anything.

Comment: It's a drastic solution but most people don't update their dependencies that often anyway - so this is a good practice to refresh where your project is at.

Answer (score 84):

`npm rebuild node-sass` was giving me errors (Ubuntu) and `npm install gulp-sass` didn't make the error go away.

Saw a solution on GitHub which worked for me:

`npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass`

`npm install --save-dev gulp-sass`

Comment: Worked Today for @lastest versions

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue:

- installing node-sass
- being told at the end of installation that the installation completed successfully
- then being asked to re-install node-sass.

The solution is to **install node-sass version 2** which supports current versions of node. See https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/490#issuecomment-70388754

Run:

```
npm install node-sass@2
```

Then re-test:

```
$ npm ls node-sass
myapp@0.0.0 /var/www/myapp
└── node-sass@2.0.1

$ gulp sass
[09:48:42] Using gulpfile /var/www/myapp/gulpfile.js
[09:48:42] Starting 'sass'...
[09:48:42] Finished 'sass' after 15 ms
```

Comment: For those of us using 'grunt-sass' be sure and update: 'npm install --save-dev grunt-sass'

Answer (score 19):

If you use Gulp then try:

`npm install gulp-sass`

I had the same problem and the `gulp-sass` package was the problem.

Comment: using this one after "npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass" fixed the problem for me

Comment: `npm install grunt-sass` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem today at work.

`npm rebuild node-sass`

done the job for me

Answer (score 9):

Downgrading Node to 0.10.36 should do it per this thread on the node-sass github page: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/490#issuecomment-70388754

If you have NVM you can just:

```
nvm install 0.10
```

If you don't, you can find NVM and instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm

Comment: solved the issue for me.
nvm is also available via homebrew for mac users: "brew install nvm". after switching to the 0.10.36 version, make sure it is really active: "node -v"

Comment: Downgrading node itself is more of a workaround than an answer.

Comment: This bug is fixed in node-sass@2.0.1- as @mikemaccana discovered at the end of the ticket referenced by this answer. See his comment in this thread.

Comment: 'grunt-sass' users should update after updating 'node-sass' if you're still experiencing trouble: 'npm install --save-dev grunt-sass'

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit orthogonal to the the OP, but --

libsass bindings don't install properly with the node-sass wrapper on Node v4.0.0. I got the same error message as in the question (`Error: 'libsass' bindings not found. Try reinstalling 'node-sass')` but I ended up uninstalling Node v4.0.0 and installing v0.12.7 using nvm, via this script:

https://gist.github.com/brock/5b1b70590e1171c4ab54

and now libsass and node-sass are behaving properly.

Answer (score 2):

you may also want to `npm remove gulp-sass` and re-install gulp-sass if you've switched node versions.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue when gulp-sass version is 1.3.0, and fix it after upgrading to 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you came here because you upgraded nodejs systemwide & suddenly your emberjs ^1.13 app is failing with this message, make sure you're not using an outdated version of `ember-cli-sass`. You'll need to `rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp` within the Ember app, then update your `package.json` with the appropriate `ember-cli-sass` version, and finally `npm install --save-dev`. This fixed it for me, without having to rebuild or change any other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I removed all the `/node_modules` folder then ran `npm install` and it worked.

I have node v5.5.0, npm 3.3.12

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused in my build system (Travis CI) by doing something kind of dumb in my `.travis.yml` file. In effect, I was calling `npm install` *before* `nvm use 0.12`, and this was causing `node-sass` to be built for `0.10` instead of `0.12`. My solution was simply moving `nvm use` out of the `.travis.yml` file’s `before_script` section to before the `npm install` command, which was in the `before_install` section.

In your case, it is likely that whatever process you are starting with `gulp` is using a different version of `node` (than what you would expect).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as @Kos had, only for some reason I had to modify the gulp-sass package from the old `package.json` file I had. It then installed the dependencies currently and now it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was on a machine with `node version 0.12.2`, but that had an old `1.x.x` version of `npm`. Be sure to update your version of npm: `sudo npm install -g npm` Once that is done, remove any existing `node-sass` and reinstall it via npm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right version. Try:

```
nvm use 0.12
```