# Gulp not running gulp-sass

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I installed a new distro (Elementary OS 0.3 Freya 64 bits) on my PC and setting up my workflow I'm having a problem running the `gulp-sass` package. When I run the `gulp` command it return the error:

```
$ gulp
[10:26:06] Using file /var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io/gulpfile.js
[10:26:06] Working directory changed to /var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io
/var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22
throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass
^
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
at getBinding (/var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:462:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:480:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (module.js:386:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projects/avanteweb.github.io/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:462:26)
```

I tried the answers on [Try reinstalling `node-sass` on node 0.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409100/try-reinstalling-node-sass-on-node-0-12) but it's still not working. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The error tells you what you need to do, so did you try following those instructions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try reinstalling \`node-sass\` on node 0.12?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409100/try-reinstalling-node-sass-on-node-0-12)

Comment: I had the same problem like you. My node v5. I removed and installed node v4. I resolved it. You can try.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from other threads, this might work for you:

```
$ npm uninstall gulp-sass node-sass
$ npm install node-sass@1.0.3 # using an older version of node-sass
$ npm install gulp-sass
```

**References:**

[Try reinstalling `node-sass` on node 0.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409100/try-reinstalling-node-sass-on-node-0-12?lq=1)

[Install fails - Windows 2008 - Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/185)

[libsass bindings not found error on v1.3.1, v1.3.2](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/174)