# How can I upgrade Libsass with npm?

Tags: node.js, sass, libsass, node-sass

I'm currently running NPM's node-sass tool, but the version of libsass it is running is 3.2.2, and the version I need to be running is 3.2.4, as this fixes a crucial bug in one of the frameworks I am using.

[image]

I can find no information on how to build and/or update either node-sass or libsass to meet my requirements. I am already running the latest version of node-sass, 3.1.2.

Yet, my node-sass `package.json` seems to have a key:value pair which indicates libsass is at 3.2.4, yet this clearly isn't correct.

**What is the easiest way to upgrade my version of libsass?**

## Updates

#### 6 June

I have done some additional searching, and still cannot get libsass to be at a version of 3.2.4. I have tried upgrading an older package of node-sass, and checking my environment variables for overrides. No solution yet.

#### 7 June

It does appear that the Libsass version that is sourced by node-sass is 3.2.4, yet it is not being picked up, and is defaulting to a Libass `binarypath`:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'vendor', sass.binaryName.replace(/_/, '/'));
```

which on my machine yields:

```
H:\myproj\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-14\binding.node
```

I have no idea what this means. Take a look at `node-sass\lib\extensions.js` on line 134:

```
sass.getBinaryPath = function(throwIfNotExists) {
  var binaryPath;

  if (flags['--sass-binary-path']) {
    binaryPath = flags['--sass-binary-path'];
  } else if (process.env.SASS_BINARY_PATH) {
    binaryPath = process.env.SASS_BINARY_PATH;
  } else if (pkg.nodeSassConfig && pkg.nodeSassConfig.binaryPath) {
    binaryPath = pkg.nodeSassConfig.binaryPath;


  // This is the only statement that executes successfully, my libsass binary path is coming from this location. Why?
  } else {
    binaryPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'vendor', sass.binaryName.replace(/_/, '/'));
  }

  if (!fs.existsSync(binaryPath) && throwIfNotExists) {
    throw new Error(['`libsass` bindings not found in ', binaryPath, '. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?'].join(''));
  }

  return binaryPath;
};

sass.binaryPath = sass.getBinaryPath();
```

Comment: I have added a manual method. Try it out.

Comment: Are you sure your question isn't answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409100/try-reinstalling-node-sass-on-node-0-12

Comment: @cinnamon, nope. This is about libsass, a dependency of node-sass.

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special command for that. Take a look at the `lib/extensions.js`  file. It has several intresting lines:

```
/**
 * The default URL can be overriden using
 * the environment variable SASS_BINARY_SITE
 * or a command line option --sass-binary-site:
 *
 *   node scripts/install.js --sass-binary-site http://example.com/
 *
 * The URL should to the mirror of the repository
 * laid out as follows:
 * SASS_BINARY_SITE/
 *  v3.0.0
 *  v3.0.0/freebsd-x64-14_binding.node
 *  ... etc. for all supported versions and platforms
 */
```

`Libsass` in this case is only a [source folder](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/tree/master/src). You can try to make a clean build. Remove `node-sass` and install it again.

```
npm install node-sass@3.0.0
...
node ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass --version
node-sass   3.0.0   (Wrapper)   [JavaScript]
libsass     3.2.2   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

When updating:

```
npm update node-sass
node ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass --version
node-sass   3.1.2   (Wrapper)   [JavaScript]
libsass     3.2.4   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

P.S. Be careful with `@at-root` in `3.2.4`. It is [bugged](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1210).

**Update**
If it will not solve your problem, try to remove all `npm` cache with

```
npm cache clean
```

**Second update**
Try to manually install the binding:

```
cd node-sass
rm -r vendor
node scripts/install.js --sass-binary-site https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/
```

It will output something like:

```
Binary downloaded and installed at /Users/sobolev/Documents/github/modernizr-mixin/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-14/binding.node
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to get this to work. I have checked my environment variables; there is nothing overriding the choice of libsass used, and I could not install node-sass 3.0.0 without errors. Libsass is still 3.2.2.

Comment: Have you tried to completely remove node-sass? What errors do you get?

Comment: Yes. I have removed and installed node-sass a dozen times now, different versions, locally, globally, without success.

Comment: May be it is a cache issue? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't appear to be. `npm cache clean`'d, and reinstalled both node-sass and gulp-sass. Still not working :(

Comment: Last try, installing from git: `npm install` [this version](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.1.2). If nothing, try to manually download proper binding from there (win32, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git
2. cd node-sass
3. git checkout tags/v3.1.2
4. npm install . -g
5. node-sass -v

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of node-sass 3.2.0 says

> This release bumps Libsass to 3.2.5 which brings with it a bunch of
>   fixes.

`npm install node-sass` will install now install a node-sass with a libsass >= 3.2.5.

Comment: Installing the current version at time of writing gave me node-sass 3.2.0 and libsass 3.2.5. If you want to have a compatible version of libsass 3.2.4+ with your version of node-sass without doing a bunch of self maintenance, just do the upgrade now.