# Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?') using node-sass running ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, sass, gulp

I updated my npm and ionic yesterday and my ionic project that was originally working is giving me this error.

```
Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?');
```

I tried

```
sudo npm install node-sass
sudo npm -g install node-gyp
sudo npm rebuild node-sass
```

but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409100/try-reinstalling-node-sass-on-node-0-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use sudo with npm. You will have lot of problems with permissions if you do that. And for your issue, this helped me:

```
npm cache clean && node ./node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
```

Try also removing all node modules before that (whole folder), run npm install (without sudo) and then if it doesn't work run the command that I wrote.