# I got the following error in node version 8+

Tags: node.js, css-modules

Previous node version is 7.9.0. The project was running well.
When I upgraded it to 8.9.4, I got the following errors.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/sass/styles.scss
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding F:\LogicSoft-SRL\angular-frontdesk\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
```

How can I fix this error in the current version(8.9.4)?

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder and npm install again. Or just delete node-sass folder from node_modules and npm install again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you have to rebuild node-sass for your node version. You can do this by running the command from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30067395/5538786).

`npm rebuild node-sass`

You can find more info on the rebuild command [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild).